# Can`t debug pic32 microcontroller or update the configuration bits

Tags: debugging, configuration, microcontroller, bit, pic

i have an PIC32MX460L512 microcontroler( Cerebot MX4 board from Digilent) and after doing some projects, i can`t program it any more.

This happend after i tested the board multipliers and dividers to see how the board works using #pragma pll ....

i can not write a new hex or change the configuration bits, and i get the following errors

1. PIC32 Starter Kit hardware initialization failure. Error= -1004, Detail=0x80004005, (LID:29)
   or a second error
2. Device reset failed/ make sure Configuration Bits are correct.

I think the board still works because windows can see it in the Devices and Printers.

what ca i do? can i reset the memory from some bits? i`m still a noob with microcontrollers.

Thanks in advance

Comment: How are you powering this board?  Is it getting good power from the USB cable or your power supply?  If you are getting power from the USB, make sure no other I/O is connect to the board (just in case those draw power from USB power), you can only get so much power out of one USB connection, if that's the problem, then try an external PS or a different USB port.

Comment: Hi, i removed everything connected to it and i still can`t program it. 
i power it on, start mplab give the command to program it. The programmer LED is turned on but after that i get the MPLAB error, normally it should blink 3 times and start running the code

Answer (score 3, accepted):

the problem was the configuration bits that i wrote earlier. i googled a little more and found that there is a file -- sk_erase.exe -- that erases the configuration bits

Comment: +1 for finding your own answer and posting it. If that did it for you then I believe you can mark it as the answer. Also problems related to wrong config bit configurations are pretty common I think. If you can elaborate some more on what config bits were wrong and what the correct values were supposed to be then it'd be a big help to future newbs.

Comment: i don`t know what i did wrong, i tested different configurations. now i use 
#pragma config FPLLMUL = MUL_20, FPLLIDIV = DIV_2, FPLLODIV = DIV_1, FWDTEN = OFF
#pragma config POSCMOD = HS, FNOSC = PRIPLL, FPBDIV = DIV_1

Comment: Assuming your board uses a 8Mhz crystal, those values look about right. When I have this sort of problem it's either misconfigured divider values (PIC's need a certain freq into the PLL) or a non-functioning crystal (not likely if you're using a dev board). That's OK though, next time you have this sort of problem you now have some items to check when you troubleshoot.